# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I think [Which should I choose "to distribute", 'distributed", or "distributing"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/137218/) should be closed as it is asking for proofreading. I don't have commenting or flagging privileges yet.

It was titled “[Which sentence is correct?4](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137218/which-sentence-is-correct4)”. The 4 is there because there is already a question named “[Which sentence is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16768/which-sentence-is-correct)” which is closed. It has the following content (it's block quoted in the question):

> 1.The marketing director showed the annual profits **to distribute** equally between the corporate executives and the shareholders to the CEO
>
> 2.The marketing director showed the annual profits **distributed** equally between the corporate executives and the shareholders to the CEO
>
> 3.The marketing director showed the annual profits **distributing** equally between the corporate executives and the shareholders to the CEO

Comment: No, it's not asking for proofreading, it's instead asking for the correct sentence **with respect to the part in bold** (which you haven't included) – i.e., the source of concern is specified. Nevertheless, it'd be nice if the asker included more details or, more precisely, the meaning they want the sentence to convey.

Comment: It might be closed as needing additional details or context, but since the answer adequately answers the question I would leave it alone. Though if the OP does not respond it is hard to know if it helped or not. It is a toss up whether such questions should be answered based on an assumption of what the OP needs vs. closing for more info. first.

Comment: I don't think it should be closed because it's asking for proofreading, but I do think it deserves a downvote because it's scant on details.

Comment: To me, it is just giving three different sentences, without the OP saying what he thinks the difference would be. I don't see any explicit, not too broad,  question too, except the one in the title, but for me a question in the title doesn't mean asking an explicit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not proofreading.  Proofreading would be something like:

> Hi can you tell me if this sentence is right? "The marketing director showed the annual profits to distribute equally between the corporate executives and the shareholders to the CEO." Thanks.

In my example there is no effort to explain which part of the sentence is confusing, or how the question can be made useful to others who might ask something similar in the future.  Really, it's just asking us to do work for free.

As others have pointed out, the actual question asked is not as complete as it could be, but at least it narrows down the problem to a choice between three similar, potentially confusing verb tenses. With a little more effort it would have been fine.